# Single and double tap home button behaviour for applicationWillResignActive

Tags: ios, objective-c, background

I'm doing an app that has some sensible data, so I need to hide the preview screens if the user enters in background mode, e.g. by showing a black screen if the user double taps on home button.

[image: Protective screen]

I'm doing this inside **applicationWillResignActive** method, by adding a black screen on UIWindow. It is working fine for both single and double tap on home button on iOS8, but on iOS7 only adds the black screen when the user double tap on home button, but no when single tapping on it (it shows the app without the black screen).

I've just realised that the **applicationWillResignActive** method is being called much later if the user single taps on home button, but I have no idea why it is only adding the black screen on double tap. This is the method I call on applicationWillResignActive.

```
- (void)addSplashImage
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) {
        self.splashImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.frame];

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            self.splashImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Splash"];
        } else {
            self.splashImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SplashiPhone"];
        }
    } else {
        CGRect frame = self.window.bounds;
        if ([TWConstants isRunningiOS8]) {
            self.splashImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        } else {
            self.splashImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.height, frame.size.width)];
        }
        self.splashImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SplashLandscape"];
    }

    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    [window addSubview:self.splashImageView];
   // [window bringSubviewToFront:self.splashImageView];
}
```

Have you got any idea of why is this happening? I've tried by bringing the splash image to the front, with no success. This is happening **only on iOS7**. Thanks!